# Determining the minimum of a linear function subject to a quadratic inequality constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gre-exam, qclp

What is the minimum value of $x+4z$, a function defined on $\mathbb{R^3}$, subject to the constraint $x^2 + y^2 +z^2 \leq 2$?

I know how to solve this if the constraint is an equality, but what shall I do if it's an inequality? Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: First optimize it in the interior (gradient $\vec 0$).  Then use Lagrange to optimize on the boundary.  Compare the results.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  Oh, clearly not.  But I understood the OP to be asking for a general methodology.   In this case, it takes just a line to note that the given function never has $0$ gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective function $u=x+4z$ does not depend on $y$, therefore $y$ must be minimum, that is $y=0$ so that $x,z$ are the maximum negative values.

Thus the new optimization problem states: Minimize $u=x+4z$ subject to $x^2+z^2\le 2.$

The feasible region is a circle with the radius $\sqrt{2}$ and the contour line of the objective function is $z=-\frac14x+\frac14u$.

Minimum of $u(x,z)$ occurs when the contour line is tangent to the feasible region from below:
$$z=-\sqrt{2-x^2} \Rightarrow z'=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}=-\frac14 \Rightarrow x=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{17}} \Rightarrow z=-\sqrt{\frac{32}{17}} \Rightarrow$$
$$u=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{17}}-4\sqrt{\frac{32}{17}}=-\sqrt{34} \ (min).$$

Comment: I think there is a typo in line 5, $ z = \frac{u-x}{4}$... right?

Comment: Right, fixed it.

Comment: why we changed the inequality of the constraint to an equality? could you tell me the intuition behind this please?

Comment: The feasible region is the circle (inequality) and the max and min values of the objective function are achieved at the border of the feasible region (equality). It is called an extreme point theorem.

Comment: It is called an an extreme point theorem or extreme value theorem ? could u please give me a link for it ?

Comment: check out the slide 8 of the PPT file here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWuIq10f7UAhUGuRoKHZxqC2cQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ccs.neu.edu%2Fhome%2Flieber%2Fcourses%2Fcsu670%2Ff08%2Flectures%2FLP.ppt&usg=AFQjCNGQVE2ZuUKszXR7OlLqVpiqL2-7aA

Answer (score 1):

You might as well force $y=0$ since that gives the largest set of pairs $(x,z)$.

Thus, the new problem is to minimize $x+4z$, defined on $\{(x,z) \in \mathbb{R^2}\}$, subject to the constraint $x^2 + z^2 \leq 2$.

Clearly, the minimum value of $x+4z$ will be negative, and the point $(x,z)$ where the minimum occurs will have $x,z$ both non-positive (with at least one of$\;x,z\;$negative).

But then, for a point $(x,z)$ where the minimum occurs, scaling the point $(x,z)$ by a constant greater than $1$ would make $x+4z$ even more negative.

It follows that the minimum value of $x+4z$ will occur on the part of the circle $x^2 + z^2=2$ in the third quadrant (possibly including the endpoints of the arc).

So now you have minimization with an equality constraint.

Can you finish it?

Comment: yes, I can thank u soo much.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following quadratically constrained linear program (QCLP) in $\mathrm x \in \mathbb R^3$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathrm c^\top \mathrm x\\ \text{subject to} & \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 \leq 2\end{array}$$

where $\mathrm c := (1,0,4)$. Since the objective function is *linear* and *nonzero*, the minimum is attained at the boundary, i.e., on the Euclidean sphere of radius $\sqrt 2$ and centered at the origin. Hence, we have the following equality-constrained QCLP in $\mathrm x \in \mathbb R^3$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathrm c^\top \mathrm x\\ \text{subject to} & \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 = 2\end{array}$$

---

#### Via Cauchy-Schwarz

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

$$\mathrm c^\top \mathrm x \geq - \| \mathrm c \|_2 \| \mathrm x \|_2 = - \sqrt{17} \cdot \sqrt{2} = - \sqrt{34}$$

Thus, the *minimum* is $\color{blue}{-\sqrt{34}}$, which is attained at $\mathrm x_{\min} = \gamma \mathrm c$, where $|\gamma| = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\| \,\mathrm c \|_2} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{17}}$. Thus,

$$\mathrm x_{\min} = \color{blue}{- \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{\frac{2}{17}}\\ 0\\ 4 \sqrt{\frac{2}{17}}\end{bmatrix}}$$

---

#### Via Lagrange multipliers

Let the Lagrangian be

$$\mathcal L (\mathrm x, \lambda) := \mathrm c^\top \mathrm x + \lambda \left( \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 - 2 \right)$$

Taking the partial derivatives of $\mathcal L$ and finding where they vanish, we obtain

$$\begin{array}{rl} \mathrm c + 2 \lambda \mathrm x &= 0_3\\ \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 &= 2\end{array}$$

Hence, $\mathrm x = - \frac{1}{2 \lambda} \mathrm c$ and, from $\| \mathrm x \|_2^2 = 2$, we obtain $\lambda = \pm \sqrt{\frac{17}{8}}$. Thus,

$$\mathrm x_{\min} = - \frac{1}{2 \lambda} \mathrm c = - \sqrt{\frac{2}{17}} \, \mathrm c = \color{blue}{- \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{\frac{2}{17}}\\ 0\\ 4 \sqrt{\frac{2}{17}}\end{bmatrix}}$$

and the *minimum* is

$$\mathrm c^\top \mathrm x_{\min} = - \sqrt{\frac{2}{17}} \| \mathrm c \|_2^2 = \color{blue}{-\sqrt{34}}$$

---

#### Via SDP

Using the Schur complement test for positive semidefiniteness, the original *inequality*-constrained QCLP can be rewritten as the following semidefinite program (SDP)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathrm c^\top \mathrm x\\ \text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_3 & \mathrm x \\ \mathrm x^{\top} & 2\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_4\end{array}$$